# Extracting variables from text file (C++)

Tags: c++

I need to input four variables into a C++ program (Win32) from a text file. Each of the variables are on their own line.

example.txt:

```
2.651127
-7.802776
5.530998
-17.239931
```

These four variables will each be a float in my program. What is the syntax in C++ to pass each line to its own variable? There are only ever four numbers, each on their own line.

Comment: Are you reading the file in inside your app, or piping it in from the command line?  Very different answers depending on this!

Comment: Will be reading the txt file into the app.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question - you can read a txt file in using something like fread or fstream, or you can pipe the txt file into the app directly from the command line, so using e.g. getline or cin could be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#include <fstream>
std::ifstream file("test.txt");
double a, b, c, d;
if(!(file >> a >> b >> c >> d)){
// error extracting the values!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double d[4];
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
  cin >> d[i];
```